# Delete old civi event locations

Tags: civievent, addresses, location

I want to condense the list of event locations to ones actually in use, and quickly update the contact details to reflect changes in our team. I only have access through the UI and was hoping to find a list, as you can for event types and templates, but am not having much luck. I'm using 5.13.4.

Looking through past questions I'm not the only one having issues, so would be good to know any fixes or if this is being addressed in the next upgrade!

Comment: They seem to be stored in civicrm_loc_block and civicrm_address (null contact_id, location type = 1). Don't know of a way to delete via UI.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to cover it: [Edit 'existing locations' for events](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10505/edit-existing-locations-for-events)

"If you are wanting to do a one-off cleanup of obsolete addresses than as a UI work around you could edit the old events that contain those obsolete locations and set the first address line to DO NOT USE or NO LONGER IN USE or similar"